# Use C# to loop through XML document and if condition is met replace value or node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a **XDocument** with XML `XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(doc1)`
I want to to loop through XML document and if condition is met replace value or node.

I tried code like:

```cs
var list = from item in xdoc1.Root.Element("New").Elements() select item;
        
foreach (XElement item in list)
{
    foreach (var node in item.Nodes())
    {
        if (node.ToString() == "DIV||&lt;Control&gt;")
        {
            item.Element("Value").Value = "DIV||TextBox";
        }
    }
```

But it does not work for me.

If my XML looks like this

```
<Test>
  <New>
    <DoSometing>
      <Selector>
      </Selector>
      <Value>DIV||&lt;Control&gt;</Value>
    </DoSometing>
    <DoSometingElse>
      <Selector>
      </Selector>
      <Value>DIV||&lt;Control&gt;</Value>
    </DoSometingElse>
  </New>
</Test>
```

So my idea is to loop through all the xml and if the condition `==` `&lt;Control&gt;` then replace it.

I also tried suff like `IEnumerable<XElement> list = from item in xdoc1.Root.Element("New").Elements() where (item.Name == "Value") select item;`

Comment: Can you provide more information about what isn't working, i.e., an error or stack trace? Also it would be helpful to know if the XML that is being processed is different than the one being posted; there are no elements in the sample with the name `TestSteps`.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider filtering the elements in the query block, and only applying updates to the elements that are necessary. Note that the `XElement.Value` is being used here, so the decoded element value has to be used.

```cs
var list = from item in xdoc1.Root.Element("New").Elements().Elements("Value") 
           where item.Value == "DIV||<Control>"
           select item;

foreach (XElement item in list)
{
    item.Value = "DIV||TextBox";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat simpler version.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\hala.xml";
    const string searchFor = "DIV||<Control>";
    const string replaceWith = "789";

    //XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@" < Test >
    <New>
        <DoSometing>
            <Selector>
            </Selector>
            <Value>DIV||&lt;Control&gt;</Value>
        </DoSometing>
        <DoSometingElse>
            <Selector>
            </Selector>
            <Value>DIV||&lt;Control&gt;</Value>
        </DoSometingElse>
    </New>
</Test>");

    // step #1: find element(s) based on the search value
    var xmlFragment = xdoc.Descendants("Value")
       .Where(d => d.Value.Equals(searchFor));
    
    // step #2: if found, set its value
    foreach (XElement element in xmlFragment)
    {
        element.SetValue(replaceWith);
    }
}
```